# My Excel 2010 macro shortcuts do not work when i first launch Excel, but works only if I first manually run it from within VBE

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts

I've created a few excel macros meant to help with number and text formatting (adding comma separators such as in 1,000,000 but without decimals; changing font colours etc.). These have been saved in a module in Personal Workbook such that they will be available whenever I use Excel.

The formatting code works fine (to the best of my knowledge), and is as shown below:

```
Sub Number_commas()

   Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Font_colour()

For Each cell In Selection

  If Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
      Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
  ElseIf Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then
      Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
  Else
      Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  End If

Next

End Sub
```

I have also tried to assign them shortcuts using OnKey. This is because I would like to be able to use characters that the Macro options window (called from Alt + F8) does not allow. This is shown below:

```
Sub Hotkey_Number_commas()

  Application.OnKey "+^1", Procedure:="Number_commas"

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Hotkey_Font_colour()

  Application.OnKey "+^:", Procedure:="Font_colour"

End Sub
```

The problem that I am facing is that every time I open Excel, these shortcuts do not work unless I manually go into VBE and run through each code. The shortcuts then work fine after that until Excel is closed and relaunched and the issue recurs. I have seen screenshots on help websites that show that the author has an option of assigning <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> shortcuts from the Macro window, but bizarrely I do not have that option, only <kbd>CTRL</kbd> shortcuts.

I'm at my wit's end and am not sure if it's a problem with my one-liner codes, or my excel / computer settings. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See http://support.microsoft.com/KB/265113 which explains how to make macros run when you open the workbook.

Try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "+^1", Procedure:="Number_commas"
    Application.OnKey "+^:", Procedure:="Font_colour"
End Sub
```